# Does this geometry theorem have a name?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Start with a circle and draw two tangent circles inside. The (black) inner tangent lines to the smaller circles intersect the large circle. The (red) lines through these intersection points are parallel to the (green) outer tangents to the small circles.

A long time ago I worked on this theorem, but I never knew the name. Without a name it's difficult to find more information. Does anyone know if this theorem has a name and where I can find more information about it?

[image: Image of the theorem]

Comment: If it doesn't have a name, you can rightfully call it "angry dude" (or some variation thereof) :-)

Comment: This reminds me of the following problem from an old issue of "Kvant" (around mid-80s). Consider an inscribed quadrilateral ABCD where neither pair of the opposite sides are parallel. Now form the triangle T whose vertices are intersections of lines AB and CD, AC and BD, AD and BC. Then the center of the circle in which ABCD is inscribed is the orthocenter of T. I remember that the proof had to do with poles and polars. It's probably all online, not too hard to find.

Comment: Hyperbolic Hyperbole Theorem in Two-Dimensions?

Comment: Please see similarly subject: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304300/a-generalization-of-the-sawayama-thebault-theorem

Answer (score 56):

Even more is true for this theorem. Check out this drawing from Arseniy Akopyan wonderful book of Geometry in Figures (Second, extended edition, 2017). On page 65 we find Figure 4.7.29)

[image: Figure 4.7.29)]

In the foreword, Arseniy Akopyan writes

> "It is commonly very hard to determine who the author of a certain
>   result is."

He nevertheless provides source for many of the figures in the end of his book. Unfortunately for Figure 4.7.29 he doesn't provide such a reference.

This leads me to the answer:
*Probably it doesn't have a name* (like many "geometry  theorems").

Comment: Is the inner circle in this diagram any circle tangent to the two smaller circles, or is it a specific one?

Comment: It's any circle tangent to both, just as you can replace the outer circle by any circle tangent to both.

Comment: If you draw a circle that is tangent to both of the fixed circles, but circumscribes only _one_ of them, then look at the points where it intersects the two _green_ tangents from the original post (dashed in this picture), would that make two chords that are parallel to the black / solid tangent lines? (I.e. swap the roles of the two pairs of tangent lines.)

Comment: This shows the theorem works with both tangent circles inside the"main" circle, or with both outside. I presume it also works with one inside and one outside?

Comment: @user1998586 As I point out in my comment right above yours, I believe it does, only you have to swap the role of the two pairs of tangent lines. Using the old roles clearly doesn't work, but a quick drawing I made by hand made it seem plausible that it works the other way.

Comment: @Arthur thanks, I was too excited by the diagrams to read the comments!

Comment: @user1998586 I can understand that. I haven't really been able to let this problem go myself. Can't wait until I have some time for myself to sit down and try to prove it, both the two posted, confirmed results and the conjecture we have made here. Alas, that won't be until tomorrow.

Comment: I think, I've found the statement by myself, looking for a static version of Protasov's segment theorem http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SegmentTheorem/

Answer (score 11):

This is theorem 2 (the Parallel tangent theorem) in ["Two Applications of the Generalized Ptolemy Theorem"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695499) by Shay Gueron.