# A generalization of the Sawayama-Thebault theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

**1. Introduction**

The **Sawayama-Thebault** theorem is one of the best nice theorem in plane geometry. The theorem has a long history. It was published in [AMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Mathematical_Monthly) in 1938 the first solution appeared in 1973 with 24 pages), You can see detail in [here](http://geometry.ru/articles/Two_Casey.pdf) and [here](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2003volume3/FG200325.pdf).

**Theorem 1** [(Sawayama-Thebault)](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2003volume3/FG200325.pdf): Through the vertex $A$ of a triangle $ABC$, a straight line $AD$ is drawn, cutting the side $BC$ at $D$. $I$ is the center of the incircle of triangle $ABC$. Let $P$ be the center of the circle which touches $DC$, $DA$ at $E$, $F$, and the circumcircle of ABC, and let Q be the center of a further circle which touches $DB$, $DA$ in $G$, $H$ and the circumcircle of $ABC$. Then $P$, $I$ and $Q$ are collinear

[image]

Source of the Figure 1 in [here](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2003volume3/FG200325.pdf)

> > I have worked for four years to find a real nice generalization of the Thebault theorem and publish in [here](http://www.journal-1.eu/2016-3/Dao-Thanh-Oai-Another-Generalization-pp.36-39.pdf) since two years ago, but has no proof. So I am looking for the proof of the generalization of the Sawayama-Thebault theorem as follows:

**2. Generalization of the Sawayama-Thebault theorem**

**Problem 2:** *( See Figure 2). Let $ABC$ be a triangle the red circle through $B$, $C$, the blue circle tangent to $AB$, $AC$ and the red circle. Let $P$ be arbitrary point in the plane, through $P$ construct two tangent lines $PD$, $PE$ to the blue circle. Let $(O_1)$ is the yellow circle tanegnt to the right tangent line $PD$, tangent to the red circle and the sideline $BC$; $(O_2)$ is the yellow circle tanegnt to the left tangent line $PF$, tangent to the red circle and tangent to the sideline $BC$. Then three points $O_1O_2$ through a fixed point when $P$ be moved on a given line*.

[image]

**3. Construct the two yellow circles?**

**Problem 3: ([The generalization of the Sawayama Lemma](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/JLAyme.shtml#Explanation))** *The lines $GF$, $HK$ through the incenter of $ABC$ (Figure 2)*

**4. Construct the point $I'$**

[image]

**See also:**

- [Does this geometry theorem have a name?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284458/does-this-geometry-theorem-have-a-name?rq=1)

Comment: What is the definition of the point I' ?

Comment: @godelian , Thank You very much I updated

Comment: Your green circle looks blue

Comment: Thank You dear Professor @FedorPetrov

Comment: That's nice generalization for Sawayama Thebault's Theorem.